# PHP different servers and security

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have several servers, the main ones a web server and an internal storage server. Data is stored in a SQL server database.

Without giving too much access to the user, how would I pull a specific document from the storage server for display to the user from the web server?

For example, I have document c:/memberID/info.pdf on the storage server and I want to display it to the client via PHP without giving them access to the internal storage server.

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `readfile` as well as `headers`

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: This will only work if the storage server is mounted on the webserver or the file is privately available via http.

Comment: I can access the storage server from the webserver via \\server.

My files are stored in the database as \\server\memberno.pdf - I want to display the link as 'document.pdf'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Simply change the variable `$file` to contain the path of the file that you want to serve: `$file = '\\server\memberno.pdf'` (make sure to appropriately escape when necessary).  tftd, I know that only works for reachable files, but it was my understanding that the files are reachable from the web server

Comment: Ok so I have managed to crack this problem for the most part.
The next part that I am stuck on is how do I transfer this into an an anchor tag in the link, without passing the filepath via $_REQUEST?

Comment: That would be a new question.  but I would suggest to create a database with `hash`,`file_with_path` and just pass the hash in the URL